# Installed CentOS 7 along with Windows 10 but no Windows boot manager option in GRUB

Tags: centos, dual-boot

I have installed CentOS 7 alongside Windows 10. However, GRUB does not give the option for Windows boot manager but it does find it with **os-prober**. In order to boot into Windows 10 I have to change the boot priority to boot into Windows boot manager which is less than ideal. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1.) EFI/UEFI? 2.) Check for /etc/grub.cfg or /etc/grub-efi.cfg symlink. 3.) Check for the file pointed by the symlink to be existing/updated. 4.) Priority is configured in /etc/default/grub (at least on Fedora), but you can also create a script like e.g. 09_windows in grub.d to select it as first one. Grub must use the "Windows boot manager chain" but you can also configure the Bootmanager to launch grub. 5.) If EFI/UEFI: Is /boot/efi actually mounted? 6.) See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2 for updating grub config like e.g. grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg

Comment: Figured it out. So i did some more digging and went to this link https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-reinstalling_grub_2 and followed the instructions i noticed at the very end instead of using grub2-mkconfig -o/boot/grub2/grub.cfg i needed to run that command on the EFI directory and it worked after that. pretty dumb for me to miss but hopefully this thread can help someone in the future

Comment: if you want to submit your comment as a answer i will approve it

Comment: Thanks. I had to "strip" my comment due to comment length limitation. As answer I wrote some more details into it.

Comment: And I tried to be more "generic" and added some additional hints.

Comment: awesome answer has been approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) The grub config depends on the boot mode: UEFI/EFI or BIOS/legacy.
Depending on this you must use

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

for BIOS/legacy and

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg
```

for UEFI (and IMHO EFI).

2.) There must be one/two symlinks to the matching config:

```
$ ls -l /etc/grub2.cfg 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Jan  1  2013 /etc/grub2.cfg -> ../boot/grub2/grub.cfg
$ ls -l /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 31 May  7  2016 /etc/grub2-efi.cfg -> ../boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

Please check that they exist.

3.) Check for the files the symlink(s) point to that at least the matching one does exist and is being updated. If not updated then use grub2-mkconfig.

4.) Priority is configured in /etc/default/grub (at least on Fedora), but you can also create a script like e.g. 09_windows in /etc/grub.d/ to select it as first one. Regarding Windows Boot Manager: Grub must use the "Windows boot manager chain" but you can also configure the Bootmanager to launch grub.

5.) If UEFI (or EFI): Is /boot/efi actually mounted? The EFI partition needs to be mounted here.

6.) See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2 for grub or the doc URL you used: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-reinstalling_grub_2

Just FYI: For kernel package installations/upgrades "grubby" will be used to update the grub config.
EDIT, hint on installation: Be sure that you don't mix up the boot modes. If you e.g. installed Windows in UEFI mode and after that installed CentOS or Fedora in BIOS mode then "grub install" won't "find" or "see" any Windows installation.